# BASH function not escaping control characters

Tags: shell-script, bashrc, bash-scripting

I have a function that I'm using to find stuff, but unfortunately anytime I pass it a control character (`$intVal` or `testing :` etc) it chokes. I was wondering what the fix was?

I can understand that using `$` or `%` or `:` etc in grep without escaping causes this issue, but since I'm passing it in by reference I'm not sure how to escape it...

Anyway, here's the code.

```
function ffind()
{
     if [ $1 ] ; then
         find -type f | grep -ir '$1' * | grep -v '.svn'
     else
         echo "'$1' is not a valid resource"
     fi
}
```

Example(s):

```
$ ffind $intVal
'' is not a valid resource

$ ffind "testing :"
bash: [: testing: unary operator expected
'testing :' is not a valid resource
```

Comment: have you tried changing the single quote for double? "$1" instead of '$1'. Those are not the same in bash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### First example

```
$ ffind $intVal
'' is not a valid resource
```

This does not work because **`$foo` is the syntax for variables**, and you don't have a variable named `intVal` set, so `$intVal` is translated to an empty string. Since the variable is also unquoted, no arguments at all are passed to `ffind`.

To fix this, escape the `$` – either **`\$intVal`** (backslash) or **`'$intVal'`** (single-quoted).

If you actually *have* a variable named `intVal`, though, put it in **double** quotes instead – **`"$intVal"`** – this will expand the variable's value, but will not split it.

Note that there is *no such thing* as "pass by reference" in bash. There is only pass-by-value and (tricky) pass-by-name.

### Second example

```
$ ffind "testing :"
bash: [: testing: unary operator expected
'testing :' is not a valid resource
```

This does not work because **you forgot to put quotes around `$1`** in the `if [ $1 ]` line, therefore it is **subject to word-splitting**, and three arguments are passed to the `[` builtin:

- "`[`"
- "`testing`"
- "`:`"
- "`]`"

instead of the expected two:

- "`[`"
- "`testing :`"
- "`]`"

Example #1 is also affected by this, since `[ $1 ]` splits to ("`[`", "`]`") and not ("`[`", "`​`", "`]`"). Example #1 works by accident, though, since apparently `[ ]` is valid. (I didn't know that...)

To fix this problem, put double quotes around `$1` – `[ "$1" ]`.

**Note:** While `[` is standard, there also is a bash-specific `[[` operator, which actually has different parsing rules from the rest of the code – in particular, it does not split expanded variables. In bash, `[[ $1 ]]` and `[[ "$1" ]]` are both equivalent, unlike their `[` alternatives.

### More bugs

Your function also has several other problems that are not shown in the examples.

```
find -type f | grep -ir '$1' * | grep -v '.svn'
```

In this line:

1. The word `'$1'` has single quotes around it. This means that *bash* will not expand its contents – you're actually telling *grep* to search for the regex `$1`, and not for the command-line argument.

   To fix this, use double quotes instead – `"$1"`
2. The first *grep* command is being told to recursively search the **contents** of all files in the current directory (`-r` and the `*` wildcard).

   At the same time, you are piping the output of `find -type f` into *grep* – seemingly trying to tell *grep* to search the **names** of all files.

   This won't work because *grep*, like most filters, will not read from stdin if given one or more files to search. I don't know what you are trying to search – file names or file contents – so pick one:

   - To search just file names, keep the pipe but remove the file specification:

     ```
      find -type f | grep -i "$1" | ...
     ```
   - To search just file contents, remove the `find|` instead:

     ```
      grep -ir "$1" * | ...
     ```
   - It *is* possible to combine both, by explicitly giving *grep* the "stdin" file:

     ```
      find -type f | grep -i "$1" - * | ...

      find -type f | grep -i "$1" /dev/stdin * | ...
     ```

     (`/dev/stdin` works with all Linux programs, while `-` is a convention used by *some* programs, including grep.)
3. In the second *grep* command, the search regex is a bit too broad. (Remember that it is a regex, not a fixed string.) `.svn` would match even something like "`not-a-svn-file`".

   To exclude the `.svn` directory, use `grep -v "/\.svn/"` instead.

   If searching file *content* (`grep -ir ...`), it is even better to get rid of the `grep -v` command entirely, and add `--exclude-dir=".svn"` to the first one.

### You can stop reading at this point

Items below are just good practice in *sh* scripts.

1. The `function` keyword is unnecessary: `ffind() { ...` is sufficient, and works in all POSIX shells (while `function ffind` *would not*).
2. If a script, program, or function fails, it should return a "failure" status to its parent. By convention, Unix programs consider `0` to mean "success" and anything else "failure" (though there are exceptions to the latter).

   To return a status explicitly, use `return <num>` in a function (or `exit <num>` in a standalone script):

   ```
   else
       echo "'$1' is not a valid resource" >&2
       return 1
   fi
   ```
3. Similarly, error messages should not be mixed with normal stdout, but written to *stderr* (fd #2) instead, using the `>&` redirection operator (see the above example). This way you can redirect the normal output to a file (e.g. `ffind intVal > results.txt`) while still having errors displayed on screen.

### Fixed code

```
ffind()
{
     if [ "$1" ] ; then
         grep -ir --exclude-dir=".svn" "$1" .
     else
         echo "'$1' is not a valid resource" >&2
         return 1
     fi
}
```

### Better tools

[ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) claims to be "better than grep". Running `ack "testing :"` would search your source code, and automatically skip `.svn` and similar directories.